Callable Arrays in PHP since 7.0
I noticed that since PHP 7.0, I can use syntax like this:
<?php

["a", "b"]();

When I run it, I encounter the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'a' not found in ...

It seems that the PHP interpreter tries to resolve ["a", "b"] as a reference to a class a with a method b and attempts to invoke it.

Why does PHP interpret this array in this way?
What is the underlying mechanism behind this behavior?
Is there any official documentation or resources that explain this feature?


Isn't this the classic callable syntax? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

@shingo, yes that seems pretty close. However, it appears to only talk about arrays instead of callables in method calls like call_user_func. I can't find any documentation explaining why arrays can also be called directly like functions.

I think it makes sense, when you look at it in combination with variable functions. $func = 'foo'; $func(); will invoke foo - and same would "foo"() or 'foo'(). So that the same logic gets applied, when you "supply" an array instead of a string with a function name, seems only logical and consistent.

@miken32 Although I understand why you marked it as a duplicate, the questioner here was primarily seeking an answer to the "why", and rightfully so: the PHP Docs don't mention the introduction of this functionality anywhere. I deduced this in an answer, and deceze perhaps expressed it more eloquently by noting that this might be a "side effect" of the new major changes in PHP 7.0.

Syntax
The introduction of the "callable arrays" mechanism, mentioned earlier, made it possible to interpret the syntax in the question. The ["a", "b"]() means that PHP tries to call the method b from the class a. However, if a is not an existing class, PHP tries to interpret a as a class name and attempts to load it. If it's not found - as in your case - the following error is displayed: Class 'a' not found.

Type 2: Static class method call.
call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod'));


Source: Callbacks / Callables - PHP Docs - mentioned by shingo

The quoted example can be converted into the short array syntax []() in PHP 7.0+ as follows:
['MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod']();


Example #4 Complex callables
$func = array(new Foo, "baz");
$func(); // prints "baz"


Source: Variable functions - PHP Docs - mentioned by C3roe

The quoted example can be converted into the short array syntax []() in PHP 7.0+ as follows:
[(new Foo), 'baz']();

The examples taken from the documentation were originally written using the array() syntax, which I have converted to the shortened [] syntax.
Tracking progress

Made assert() accept the array(&$obj, 'methodname') syntax

Source: PHP 4.1.1 Changelog - Dec 10, 2001

I think this release helped pave the way for the later update that made arrays callable.

Added short array syntax support ([1,2,3])

Source: PHP 5.4 Changelog - Mar 01, 2012

I just mention this, as it allows us to shorten the frequently mentioned array() in the documentation to [].

PHP 5.6 sandbox: ['a', 'b'](); not working
PHP 7.x sandbox: ['a', 'b'](); successfully
PHP 8.x sandbox: ['a', 'b'](); successfully

I couldn't find specific entries in the changelogs or migration guides about this feature's progress. However, it's clear that it became functional in PHP 7.x due to major updates in callable handling. By PHP 8.x, this syntax is fully supported and works as expected for all callables.

I believe the major change in PHP 7 was the switch to a better/proper AST parser. Before it just wasn’t expected that you’d construct an array and call it immediately, so that syntax didn’t work. But since callable arrays are really just callable arrays, []() should logically always have worked. With the proper AST, it now does. That’s more a side effect than a conscious choice, I’d say.
